# Deploying .NET Core Web API to IIS Server

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I created my first .Net Core Web API and trying to deploy it to a remote IIS server. I use a `create-react-app` project for the front end.

When I debug locally and communicate with .Net Core WEB API, it works fine:

> `https://localhost:5001/api/notes`

I use `https://myapp.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com` as my public URL (here *myapp* is an example), and everything looks fine on browser that the front end pages load correctly.

But when I testing backend APIs by fetching `get` on

> `https://myapp.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/api/notes`

I got **404**.

My IIS configuration:
[image: My IIS configuration:]

The `web.config` on .Net Core Web API build folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\myapp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>

  </location>

</configuration>
```

And React `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".js" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="application/javascript; charset=UTF-8" />
        </staticContent>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**UPDATED**:

My `DbContext` EF Core instance:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Notes.DB
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
        public DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }

        public AppDbContext(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
               Configuration.GetConnectionString("myDb1"));
        }
    }
}
```

And, `appsettings.json` in .Net Core Project:

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "Secret": ""
    },
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "myDb1": 'I generated this string from Azure SQL Database'
    }
}
```

My `Controller` code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Notes.Core;
using Notes.DB;

namespace myApp.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [Bind("Id,Username,Value")]

    public class NotesController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly ILogger<NotesController> _logger;
        private INotesServices _notesSerives;
        private readonly AppDbContext _context;

        public NotesController(ILogger<NotesController> logger, INotesServices notesSerives, AppDbContext context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _notesSerives = notesSerives;
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet("", Name = "GetAllNote")]
        public IActionResult GetAllNote()
        {
            return Ok(_notesSerives.GetAllNote());
        }

    }
}
```

What I did wrong? How to debug this?

Comment: This site has all of this 
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Mar/16/ASPNET-Core-Hosting-on-IIS-with-ASPNET-Core-22

Comment: Based on the limited information on IIS configuration you shared, the proper URL is probably `https://myapp.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/api/notes`

Comment: @LexLi Using `https://myapp.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/api/notes` gives me a 200 but returns an HTML doc, so I am guessing the URL is still wrong?

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? Is it accessible using http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use HTTPS (using TLS for authentication), you will not receive any response if TLS fails. Therefore, the cause of this problem may be that the site you want to visit does not support HTTPS, or the URL does not exist.

You can try to use http access first, if http can be accessed successfully then this should be a certificate verification issue. If 404 still appears when using http, then .Net Core Web API should not be successfully deployed to IIS. It could also be because you used the wrong URL. For information about "Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS", you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Hi, after following your instructions I realised that the problem might be unsuccessful deployment of .Net Core API backend. I can now run https correctly, but I am getting 500 - Internal server error. So I guess something went wrong in the `config ` file?

Comment: Have you installed ASP.NET Core Module/Hosting Bundle?

Comment: Yes, I did. I accidentally installed the wrong version of the Bundle 5.0. I then removed it on the server and downloaded the .Net Core 3.1.0 which is the version of my Web API project. After restarting the IIS, I can see from the browser that the `500` remains and this time 'no response data available'.

Comment: Can IIS successfully host core MVC projects? I have to confirm whether this problem is related to IIS or the Web api project.

Comment: You must ensure that IIS can successfully host core projects.